# R: creating data frame based on sequence

Tags: r

I am not even sure how to precisely phrase the question (feel free to edit!), but here is what I want: A data frame or dplyr tibble that contains the following rows (let's say n=4)

```
col1|col2
1|1
2|1
2|2
3|1
3|2
3|3
4|1
4|2
4|3
4|4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can construct that `data.frame` using `R` functions, but maybe you want to be clearer about what principles you are looking to extract from this question.

```
n <- 4
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(1:n, 1:n), col2 = unlist(lapply(1:n, seq.int)))
df

   col1 col2
1     1    1
2     2    1
3     2    2
4     3    1
5     3    2
6     3    3
7     4    1
8     4    2
9     4    3
10    4    4
```

Comment: Also, `sequence(1:4)` gives the equivalent of `c(1,1:2,1:3,1:4)` and is just `unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))` in a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like this:

```
n <- 4
colA <- c()
colB <- c()

for (i in 1:n){
  for(j in 1:i){
    colA <- c(colA, i)
    colB <- c(colB, j)
  }
}

matrix.data <- data.frame(colA, colB)
print(matrix.data)
```